# LeetCode 177: Nth Highest Salary

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This is a famous [interview question](https://leetcode.com/problems/nth-highest-salary/):

#### Problem

Write a SQL query to get the nth highest salary from the Employee table.

```
+----+--------+
| Id | Salary |
+----+--------+
| 1  | 100    |
| 2  | 200    |
| 3  | 300    |
+----+--------+
```

For example, given the above Employee table, the nth highest salary where n = 2 is 200. If there is no nth highest salary, then the query should return null.

```
+------------------------+
| getNthHighestSalary(2) |
+------------------------+
| 200                    |
+------------------------+
```

#### MySQL Attempt

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNthHighestSalary(nHighestSalary INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    SET nHighestSalary = nHighestSalary - 1;
    RETURN(
        SELECT DISTINCT salary
        FROM employee
        ORDER BY salary DESC
        LIMIT 1
        OFFSET nHighestSalary
        );
END
```

What would be the most efficient query for the problem?

#### Reference

[177. Nth Highest Salary](https://leetcode.com/problems/nth-highest-salary/)

Comment: I also solved this question in exactly the same way as you, but I wrapped around the inner `SELECT` with an `IFNULL` because the question stated to return `NULL` if an nth highest salary did not exist. I noticed that *both* submissions were passing the tests, but the `IFNULL` made it much slower (submission time dropped from top 25% to top 55%). Any ideas on why?

Comment: The more important question, however, is one of correctness, not of efficiency. It seems as if your solution sort of implies the `IFNULL` statement, OR Leetcode simply forgot to check against the use of `IFNULL` with appropriate test cases. Do you think that your solution actually implies `IFNULL`? It would be interesting if so.

Comment: @martijn-pieters  I don't understand how this need be "more focused" to the point of getting closed?  (Even without comparing it to the atrocities I see daily in tags where I contribute regularly.) It asks about efficiency of a particular SQL problem (and code), which is an absolutely legitimate and non-trivial problem ... no?  I'd appreciate a clarification, just so...  (I also don't get why the question got trashed with -4, but that can't be explained i guess.)  Or were there some particular developments here, other than the code I can see now?

Comment: (not sure whether the tag I used above for @MartijnPieters will work so here's the right one...)

Comment: @zdim: I wonder whether mods can exercise some discretion on algorithm problems where being able to cheat would be wholly counterproductive. We have guidelines for asking for homework help too, again to prevent academic dishonesty.

Comment: @halfer "Cheat" and "dishonesty" ... ? Hum? I thought that "leetcode" is fully informal website, for anyone's practice. And it's a straight-up question, clearly stating what it is, just as there are many others for "leetcode"; a whole tag in fact.  Mods can surely do things, what is good, and whatever I've seen from Martin was great and I'm not calling mods out.  Just curious since the question seems OK to me (a bit broad but not unreasonable), and I've crossed paths with this user and  they were always very nice and respectful to all, with a clear desire to be a part of SO and contribute.

Comment: @zdim: Leetcode (or similar) is used liberally in the Big Tech interviews, from what I hear. Whether the homework guidelines were applied to this is something I can't say, but the OP has received a substantial suspension, so there is perhaps some background information we won't be party to. You can always post on Meta if you want to get some more info - just note there may be details that mods can't go into.

Comment: @halfer This is asked as an interview question, like thousands of others on "leetcode"; I don't think "homework guidelines" closed the question -- the reason given is "needs more focus." The suspension (about "voting") has nothing to do with this and it came months later. I specifically didn't mean to raise big talk, specially not in meta. Was just hoping for a simple clarification, as I was curious for the reasons stated above. If they aren't up for providing that, what seems to be the case, then fine, I'll remove these comments.  (Will let you know so you can clean up as well)  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use rank for all such SQL problems:

```
select * from
(select Salary, rank() over (order by Salary desc) as r
from Employee) a
where r = n
```

where n is the nth highest number. This requires MySQL 8.0.

Comment: I assume this needs MySQL 8.x to work? I think window functions are new to MySQL.

Comment: MySQL 8.0 is required for window functions, but 8.0 has been GA for over two years (since April 2018). If you need features that are in a specific version of the software, it's reasonable to require that version of the software.

Comment: @Emma: question authors on Stack Overflow are encouraged to take the gist of what is said in an answer, and debug it for themselves. They are, after all, in possession of the code and the development environment to try various things. Would you do some experimentation and report on your results after doing so?

Comment: @Emma: well, if the error says `Unknown column 'n'` then you perhaps did not replace `n` with `nHighestSalary`. Do please keep trying. What I am getting at is that a 23k user should not be asking a new question of an answer author as soon as a new error is encountered. You are evidently an experienced software engineer and I am sure you can do some fresh experimentation. Maybe you just need a local instance of MySQL to try some new things?

Comment: You can also use [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/), as that has a MySQL 8 installation.

Comment: This doesn't return `null` when there's no nth highest salary, it returns an empty result.

Comment: I think you need to use `DENSE_RANK()` to handle ties.